# Possible to get content block from another entry?

Tags: matrix, entry

I guess this isn't possible as it would mean the content is essentially a Global, but I would like to be able use a block from a matrix field from another entry.

At the moment I have a parent page with a block of content, which I would like to replicate on all of it's child pages. I don't want to make the user repeat it on each child page, but I don't want to hardcode it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query for that parent page's entry model with a [new ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel).

```
{% set mainEntry = craft.entries.id(100).first() %}

{% if mainEntry %}
    {% set matrixField = mainEntry.matrixFieldHandle %}
    {% set firstContentBlock = matrixField.type('content').first() %}

    {% if firstContentBlock %}
        {{ firstContentBlock.myRichTextFieldHandle }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Instead of using the entry's ID as the link to that entry, you can also use [other parameters](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) to query for the entry model. Here's an example using slug and section:

```
{% set mainEntry = craft.entries.section('news').slug('main-news').first() %}
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks! I guess the distinction I had to understand was I'm getting info from the entry, not the field. so you have to return query the model using the slug or ID. Makes sense!